# Raspberry pi servo motor angle calculation

Tags: servo

I know servo :

```
1 ms is 0 degree
1.5 ms is 90 degree 
2 ms is 180 degree
```

I also know servo motor has period of 20 ms and PWM from 1-2 ms, but i totally confused how to calculate angle like 30 or 60 or any angle between 0-180 .
So I want to enter angle and the angle will be converted to dutycycle. than can be used in `p.ChangeDutyCycle`

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
gpio.setwarnings(False)
gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(7,gpio.OUT)
pwm = gpio.PWM(7,100)
pwm.start(2.5)
def change(k):
    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(k)
    time.sleep(1)

try:
    while True:
        k = float(raw_input("enter angle: "))
        k = (1+(float(k)/180))/20
        change(k)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pwm.stop()
    gpio.cleanup()
    exit
```

Comment: As originally written the question had nothing to do with the Raspberry Pi.  However subsequent edits showed the use of the Python module RPi.GPIO which only runs on the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 4):

For the Raspberry Pi Python RPi.GPIO module (which seems to use dutycycle values between 0 and 100).

dutycycle = ((angle/180.0) + 1.0) * 5.0

so angle=0 gives 1.0 * 5 (5%), angle=90 gives 1.5 * 5 (7.5%), angle=180 gives 2.0 * 5 (10%), angle=45 gives 1.25 * 5  (6.25%) etc.

The RPi.GPIO ChangeDutyCycle method is not a reliable way to control servos.  It uses software timing which will cause servo glitches.

Comment: its pwm not ducty cylce, need to convert it to duty cycle??,

Comment: pwm = duty cycle

Comment: @Hackaholic I edited the calculation to give dutycycle values as I think are used by RPi.GPIO.

Comment: @joan yea i am using RPi.GPIO, it totally confused me

Comment: ahhh i was so stupid i was using this formula but i was multpling it wiht 100, ohhh, we dont not to multiply to 100

Comment: @joan can u check the code, i updated it whay its not working??

Comment: @Hackaholic I think you are right, you need to multiply by 100 for RPi.GPIO, so try dutycycle = ((angle/180.0) + 1.0) * 5.0.

Comment: hey what will be the range of duty cycle of f=50hz and period 20ms and pwm 1-2ms??

Comment: @Hackaholic Between 5 and 10%.